# Split legs of high poly mesh apart and rotate them. How to?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, sculpting

I have a model, but the legs are too close.
My wife made it in Nomad and I'm trying to work with it in Blender.

The model looks like this:

[image]

I don't know much about modelling in Blender, so I don't know what tool or method I'm searching for.

If I select half of the mesh, move it and rotate it, it looks like this:

[image]

I also tried deleting half of the mesh, but then it looks like this:

[image]

There is a hole at the top of the boot, because they overlap.

My question is, what is the best way to achieve the splitting in Blender?

Comment: First thing, maybe make it low-poly so that it will be easier to work with it? It looks high poly for the moment

Comment: I want to make the model ready for retopo, that's why I wanted to keep the high poly version

Comment: The legs in their current state shouldn't be a problem if you do a retopology, right? In Sculpt mode there is a mask and a pose brush that works with the mask and face sets. Since the pelvic area is smooth and there are no details in the original state, you can also smooth out any disturbing artifacts with the Smooth brush.

Comment: Ill try that later, thanks!